# Find the volume of a body bounded by surfaces

Tags: integration, volume, iterated-integrals

Find the volume of a body bounded by surfaces $z = x^2 + y^2$, $z = x + y$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the difference $x+y−x^2−y^2$
over the circle $(x−1/2)^2+(y−1/2)^2=1/2$